# JSHint saying '$' is not defined

Tags: jquery, jshint

When using jquery selectors, JSHint says that the `$` sign is not defined. For example:

```
'use strict';

// Some great code above
$('li').addClass('active');
$('li').removeClass('obsolete');
```

As you can see, this code is ok, but running `grunt jshint` I get:

```
Running "jshint:all" (jshint) task

app/scripts/stuff/script.js
  line 4  col 1  '$' is not defined.
  line 5  col 1  '$' is not defined.

✖ 2 problems
```

What should I do to remove the warning?

Comment: What was the point of asking this question if you answer it yourself, so quickly?

Comment: @T.Woody It's a feature, see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: @T.Woody So other people don't have to lose another 30 minutes searching for the solution like I did :-)

Comment: @JoshCrozier, thank you for the link! This is my first time seeing this done, so I was kind of confused. Thanks, guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSHint have [options](http://www.jshint.com/docs/options/) to customize the code parse functions so you can get ride of absurds warning.

In this case, JSHint should now that you're using jQuery to recognize the `$` sign. Do it simple enabling the [`jquery`](http://www.jshint.com/docs/options/#jquery) option in your code:

```
/*jshint jquery: true */
'use strict';

// Some great code above
$('li').addClass('active');
$('li').removeClass('obsolete');
```

Now running `grunt jshint` will output:

```
Running "jshint:all" (jshint) task

✔ No problems
```

---

For further JSHint options, look at [their page](http://www.jshint.com/docs/options/).